# User can sudo although he is not in sudo group nor in /etc/sudoers

Tags: linux, sudo

I have two colleagues on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (release 6.4). Both of them can execute the sudo commands. Curiously, only one of the colleagues is in the /etc/sudoers file - let's call him colleague A. There is no extra "sudo" group and both of the users are only in the default groups named after their username. How is it possible that colleague B can execute sudo, although he is not in /etc/sudoers?

Comment: It is very hard to comment on something that is very specific, without having seen the configuration, but taking your word as a gospel, two things come to mind: (1) the Colleague B is a member of a group which has sudo rights via a convoluted series of sudoers directives (2) Colleague B's UID matches to someone with sudo privileges. It is not an uncommon mistake to create two users with the same UID number, especially if you don't have a centralized user management control and multiple sysadmins for the same server.

Comment: See if there are `#include` or `#includedir` directives in `/etc/sudoers` file, and should there be those, see files/directories they point to.

Comment: @Sami Laine: thanks, that was the solution. There is a line "#includedir /etc/sudoers.d" in etc/sudoers. The directory /etc/sudoers.d/ contains a file with an entry for colleague B. If you want to write your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

check in `sudoers.d` dir there will be file named the user which can run sudo will be in `/etc/sudoers.d/`